# Why does my code cause stack overflow error in java? It should terminate eventually. The for loop version does not cause the error

Tags: java, stack-overflow

update 10/23/2014: I thought basically the recursive function is a void function, so no more work needed after the return, it should be equivalent to tail recursive version. And it should not cause the stack overflow. I have actually also tried the tail recursive non-void return type and it still caused the stack overflow error. I guess even though it is tail recursive, it still depends on how compiler interpreter implements it.

The for loop version of the same code does not cause stack overflow error. However the code below (recursive version) does. Essentially they should be doing the same thing. The exception error came up around loop 7000 (i=7000).

I am curious why the recursive version causes the error while the for loop version does not. I have some suspicions but not sure.

```
//recursive version, overflow

public class Solution {
    int n, low = -1, profit = 0;
    int[] a;

    public int maxProfit(int[] prices) {
        n = prices.length;
        if (n == 0 || n == 1)
            return 0;
        a = prices;
        maxProfit(1);
        return profit;
    }

    public void maxProfit(int i) {

        if (i == n - 1) {
            if (low != -1 && a[i - 1] <= a[i])
                profit += a[i] - low;
            return;
        }
        if (a[i - 1] < a[i] && low == -1) {
            low = a[i - 1];
        }
        if (a[i - 1] > a[i] && low != -1) {
            profit += a[i - 1] - low;
            low = -1;
        }
        //System.out.print(i+",");
        maxProfit(i + 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution sl = new Solution();
        // int[] a = { 1, 9, 6, 9, 1, 7, 1, 1, 5, 9, 9, 9 };
        // int[] a = { 4, 4 };
        // int[] a = { 3, 2 };
        // int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3 };
        // int[] a = { 3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 4, 9, 7 };
        int[] a = new int[100001];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100001; i++) {
            a[i] = 100000 - i;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(sl.maxProfit(a));
    }
}
```

Comment: It might have something to do with the recursive version expecting to be able to have a call stack 100000 frames deep...

Comment: Recursive functions tend to cause a StackOverflowError when your base case doesn't get hit, making the stack unwind...this can be either from messing up the base case logic, not moving towards the base case, or trying to recurse too deep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nobody so far has really explained what is happening...

When you call a function it's not simply going there--it has to remember exactly where you were and what all your variables were so it can return to that exact spot when your function returns.

It does this by storing the current state on a stack (An area of memory that builds up in one direction).  Every time your app recurses the stack grows deeper needing more memory.

A Stack overflow is when the stack has grown so big that it overflows the memory allocated to it.

your looping version doesn't require any extra memory per iteration because it doesn't have to remember when to go back to--it just runs around in circles and can do so for ever.

Sorry if this wasn't what you were asking.

Comment: It's not looping for ever. it does have an exit condition.

Comment: @jesseZhuang Of course you are correct and I did not say that at all. I just said that an iterative solution can loop forever because it's not allocating extra space per iteration (looped solution) as opposed to a recursive implementation that does allocate per iteraton and cannot loop forever.

Answer (score 1):

Your recursion depth is 100000 calls. Yes, with unlimited stack size your stack would not overflow but in practice the stack size is limited. The default stack size on a 32bit VM is 320k and 1024k on a 64 bit vm. On a 32 bit vm your particular function would use 64bits of the stack per each level of the call depth. 32 bits for integer you're passing and 32 bits for the return address. 64bits * 100000 depth = 8 bytes * 100000 depth = 800KB (approx). Which is much larger than the default stack size.

Answer (score 1):

Figured I put an answer in the comments, may as well make it a legit answer...

Recursive functions tend to cause a StackOverflowError when your base case doesn't get hit, making the stack unwind. This can be either from messing up the base case logic, not moving towards the base case, or trying to recurse too deep.

In your case, it's because you're trying to have a call stack 100001 levels deep. That's huge. You're trying to do too much recursively, and that's what's causing the problem.

Answer (score -2):

You are struck because your program has no exit condition.Look it goes into the loop maxProfit(1), but has no option of exiting from the loop.

Update:
Once your program gets into this loop there is no way for it to come out..

```
public void maxProfit(int i) {

    if (i == n - 1) {
        if (low != -1 && a[i - 1] <= a[i])
            profit += a[i] - low;
        System.out.println("i");
        return;
    }
    if (a[i - 1] < a[i] && low == -1) {
        low = a[i - 1];
        System.out.println("i");
    }
    if (a[i - 1] > a[i] && low != -1) {
        profit += a[i - 1] - low;
        low = -1;
        System.out.println("i");
    }
    //System.out.print(i+",");

    maxProfit(i + 1);
 }
```

Comment: His program does has an exit condition:
  if (i == n - 1) {
            if (low != -1 && a[i - 1] <= a[i])
                profit += a[i] - low;
            return;
        }

Comment: Wrong : `if (i == n - 1)` is an exit condition.

Comment: @Maxaon3000, I have no idea where you guys are looking at, Once it  get to maxProfit(int i), there is no way for the program to come out of it. Check the code properly.

Comment: @user2900314: read it over carefully. When i == 99999 the bottom most function in the recursion returns, unwinding the stack. I mean that is what would happen if the stack size was large enough.

Comment: @Jesse Zhuang, to validate or check my statement put a sop statement in every method.Then Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: @Maxaon3000, Look initially the for loop in main method gets executed completely and then when the sl.maxProfit(a) is called which is declared inside the SOP, there is no way for the program to come out of it, it becomes an infinite loop.

Comment: @user2900314 Look, since programming is an empirical science we don't have to keep arguing. Why don't you just set the loop counter to something like 1000 and run the code? You'll see that it comes out.

Comment: @Maxaon3000- wow, even if  you make it as low as 3 you still get out stack over flow error. I have tried it. I hope that proves my point i.e "Once your program gets into maxProfit(int i) loop there is no way for it to come out.."

Comment: @user2900314 did you remember to set the array size to 3?

Comment: @user2900314: use this main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution sl = new Solution();
        // int[] a = { 1, 9, 6, 9, 1, 7, 1, 1, 5, 9, 9, 9 };
        // int[] a = { 4, 4 };
        // int[] a = { 3, 2 };
        // int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3 };
        // int[] a = { 3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 4, 9, 7 };
        int[] a = new int[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            a[i] = 100 - i;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(sl.maxProfit(a));
    }
}

Comment: @user2900314 - look at the first line in the function you're talking about: `if (i == n - 1)` - ie: if `i` is at the end of the array - there is a `return` statement in there so it doesn't call the `maxProfit` function again and the stack would unwind. You clearly haven't actually tried it.

Comment: @Maxaon3000 thanks for your patience. Yes it has to do with the array size. Gosh, it took me so much of time.

Comment: @Chris I had tried that those, but definitely not by decreasing the array size. I was running it by changing the loop count.